# Should I use jest or jest-cli on a react native project from scratch?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, jestjs

When creating a react-native project from scratch I am getting `jest` in `devDependencies` and test passes!

But now I am getting when doing my tests:

```
(node:32629) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: Cannot find module '.../node_modules/jest-cli'
(node:32629) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Should I use jest or jest-cli?

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to know without more information, but it might be that your globally installed `jest` is older than your `packages.json` version.

Try running the following from your project directory and compare the results:

```
jest --version
npm exec jest --version
```

Also try running `npm exec jest` as that will run jest using your locally installed version.